# Could not get password database information for UID of current process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry

Tags: linux, dbus

I have dbus cross compiled for arm (Version 1.8) but it gives the following error
when I run it.

1. ```
   cdma-linux # ./dbus-launch
   Could not get password database information for UID of current
   process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry

   Failed to start message bus: Memory allocation failure in message bus
   ```
2. I have added a new user "messagebus" to */etc/passwd* file and it didn't work
3. *passwd* looks like :

   ```
    root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
    nobody:x:1104:1104:tr140 user:/mnt:/bin/false
    system:x:1000:1000:system:/bin:/bin/false
    shm:x:101:101:shm:/bin:/bin/false
    log:x:102:102:log:/bin:/bin/false
    storage:x:103:103:storage:/bin:/bin/false
    audio:x:104:104:audio:/bin:/bin/false
    update:x:2026:2026:update:/bin:/bin/false
    multiupg:x:2028:2028:multiupg:/bin:/bin/false
    cwmp:x:2065:2065:cwmp:/bin:/bin/false
    tr111:x:2069:2065:tr111:/bin:/bin/false
    web:x:2073:2073:web:/bin:/bin/false
    upnp:x:2189:2189:upnp:/bin:/bin/false
    ssdpd:x:2601:2189:upnp:/bin:/bin/false
    syslog:x:2075:2075:syslog:/bin:/bin/false
    cfgservice:x:2902:2902:cfgservice:/bin:/bin/false
    voiper:x:2213:2213:voiper:/bin:/bin/false
    utapp:x:2356:2356:utapp:/bin:/bin/false
    device:x:3073:3073:device:/bin:/bin/false
    atserver:x:3651:3651:atserver:/bin:/bin/false
    dialup:x:3647:3647:dialup:/bin:/bin/false
    net:x:3670:3670:net:/bin:/bin/false
    sms:x:3650:3650:sms:/bin:/bin/false
    hiclient:x:2774:2774:hiclient:/bin:/bin/false
    cloudeng:x:2930:2930:cloudeng:/bin:/bin/false
    ntwksync:x:2610:2189:ntwksync:/bin:/bin/false
    mcastssid:x:2945:2376:mcastssid:/bin:/bin/false
    bip:x:3075:3075:bip:/bin:/bin/false
    chrmgr:x:2198:2198:chrmgr:/bin:/bin/false
    chrlog:x:2199:2199:chrlog:/bin:/bin/false
    mlogserver:x:3006:3006:mlogserver:/bin:/bin/false
    telnet_server:x:2711:2711:telnet_server:/bin:/bin/false
    hibridge:x:2778:2778:hibridge:/bin:/bin/false
    chrprotocol:x:2074:2074:chrprotocol:/bin:/bin/false
    atproxy:x:5000:5000:atproxy:/bin:/bin/false
    audios:x:5001:5001:audios:/bin:/bin/false
    conn_mgt:x:5002:5002:conn_mgt:/bin:/bin/false
    dataming:x:5003:5003:dataming:/bin:/bin/false
    dev_comm:x:5004:5004:dev_comm:/bin:/bin/false
    econnect:x:5005:5005:econnect:/bin:/bin/false
    ese:x:5006:5006:ese:/bin:/bin/false
    fota:x:5007:5007:fota:/bin:/bin/false
    icc:x:5008:5008:icc:/bin:/bin/false
    liteipc:x:5009:5009:liteipc:/bin:/bin/false
    logd:x:5010:5010:logd:/bin:/bin/false
    miscell:x:5011:5011:miscell:/bin:/bin/false
    pdp:x:5012:5012:pdp:/bin:/bin/false
    reliable:x:5013:5013:reliable:/bin:/bin/false
    position:x:5014:5014:position:/bin:/bin/false
    rmtsrv:x:5015:5015:rmtsrv:/bin:/bin/false
    safety:x:5016:5016:safety:/bin:/bin/false
    srvmgt:x:5017:5017:srvmgt:/bin:/bin/false
    systime:x:5018:5018:systime:/bin:/bin/false
    tcs:x:5019:5019:tcs:/bin:/bin/false
    vehdata:x:5020:5020:vehdata:/bin:/bin/false
    v2xstack:x:5021:5021:v2xstack:/bin:/bin/false
    messagebus:x:5501:5501:Linux User,,,:/:/system/bin/sh
   ```
4. I made a C code to check if the database works on my device and it is.

Thanks for your support